# Usage description issue in Ionic and iOS 10 builds

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios10

My ionic application for iOS worked fine, till today when I wanted to make a new build.

This is what get's returned by Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "AppName". To process your delivery, the following
>   issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
>   make you aware of them:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
>   Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
>   is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your
>   App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal.
>   Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct
>   signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and
>   Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for
>   more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
>   service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
>   submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
>   you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
>   API.

This are my dependencies:

- `"ngstorage": "~0.3.10",`
- `"ion-image-lazy-load": "*",`
- `"ngCordova": "~0.1.24-alpha",`

And I use the Barcode scanner in ngCordova. So I did this:

`$ cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 
$ cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Scan QR-Codes" --save`

The `config.xml` has this in the bottom now:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~1.2.0">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="description" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="description" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Scan QR-Codes" />
    </plugin>
```

But still I get the same e-mail from Apple that my app has one or more issues..

Answer (score 27):

Although, almost all Cordova plugins are now updated to support user-sensitive usage description. For example, update your barcode plugin version to the latest build (as of **November 7th 2016**) where they added support for usage description:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~6.0.3">
```

But if you don't find a plugin supporting it yet and you need to set the description in `*-Info.plist` then please **YOU NEED TO STOP THERE**

Modifying the `*-Info.plist` for Cordova applications are not recommended because this will require you to save that change which might get overwritten after build process. So as the clean alternative you should use [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config).

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --save
```

> ## Why should I use it?
>
> While some platform preferences can be set via Cordova/Phonegap in the
>   config.xml, many (especially ones related to newer platform releases)
>   cannot. One solution is to manually edit the configuration files in
>   the platforms/ directory, however this is not maintainable across
>   multiple development machines or a CI environment where subsequent
>   build operations may overwrite your changes.
>
> This plugin attempts to address this gap by allowing additional
>   platform-specific preferences to be set after the prepare operation
>   has completed, allowing either preferences set by Cordova to be
>   overridden or other unspecified preferences to be set. Since the
>   custom preferences are entered into the config.xml, they can be
>   committed to version control and therefore applied across multiple
>   development machines, CI environments, and maintained between builds
>   or even if a platform is removed and re-added.

Now add the following to your `config.xml` file under `<platform name="ios">` block:

```
<custom-config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>This app needs access to your Photo Library to include a screenshot with feedback foo.</string>
</custom-config-file>
<custom-config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Allow to scan member's pass</string>
</custom-config-file>
```

This will automatically add those in your `*-Info.plist`.

#### Update 1 (23rd Feb 2018)

If you are using `cordova-custom-config` plugin version < 5 then replace `custom-config-file` tag with `config-file`.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#changes-in-cordova-custom-config5

#### Update 2 (19th Jan 2019)

See this answer for **Cordova CLI >= 6**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013943/2405040

Comment: I've been wondering why Xcode always erases my usage descriptions after a cordova build. This answer helped me greatly, thank you @Shashank Agrawal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using phonegap plugin org.apache.cordova.camera and solution which 100% works is here :

All you have to do is put values in config.xml file and build with phonegap.

My config.xml :

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera">
      <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the camera." />
      <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `NSCameraUsageDescription` into your `*.plist` in your xcode;

> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
>   NSCameraUsageDescription = Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Then into the value just add a description for those privacy settings.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: `$ cordova plugin list` and re-install all plugins and read their docs of how to install them regarding the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` etc .

Answer (score 0):

You must add the key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` into `Info.plist` (in Xcode), and the value must be the reason for the user to allow camera usage (appears in the request camera confirm dialog)

Answer (score -1):

Add the below in your config.xml file and it'll work fine.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm">
    <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="We'd like to access your camera to let you take a photo"/>
    <param name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="We'd like to access your photo library to let you pick a photo"/>
    <param name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="We'd like to access your microphone to let you record an audio"/>
</gap:plugin>
```

Here is the complete config.xml file for PhoneGap Build.
https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/blob/master/config.xml

Comment: This works only if you're using the online PhoneGap Build service from Adobe.  If you're building locally, using the CLI, then you are correct, it doesn't work at all.