# Cordova hide statusbar during show splashscreen

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Splashscreen shows by plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen. But when the application starts up and displays the splashscreen, status bar is not hidden. How can I hide statusbar when splashscreen is displayed? I found this solution:

[How to completely hide the status bar in iOS using Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795921/how-to-completely-hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-using-cordova)

But it's work on iOS. My platform is Android.

Answer (score 4):

in ionic 3 app, if `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` does **not** work, do the following:

1. Install the fullscreen plugin:

   ```
   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fullscreen
   npm install --save @ionic-native/android-full-screen
   ```
2. add this in the `config.xml` file to customize theme:

   ```
   <widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   // note this xmlns:android line
       <platform name="android">
       ...
       <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
       </edit-config>
     </platform>
   </widget>
   ```
3. add full screen provider in `src/app/app.module.ts`:

   ```
   ....
   // add this line at the top of the file, import it
   import {AndroidFullScreen} from "@ionic-native/android-full-screen";
   ...
   providers: [
     StatusBar,
     SplashScreen,    
     {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
     AndroidFullScreen,   // here add this line
     ...
   ]
   ```
4. use it in `src/app/app.components.ts`:

   ```
   // add this line at the top of the file, import it
   import {AndroidFullScreen} from "@ionic-native/android-full-screen";
   ...
   constructor(public platform: Platform,
               public statusBar: StatusBar,
               public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
               public androidFullScreen: AndroidFullScreen) {

     // show statusbar
     this.androidFullScreen.isSupported()
       .then(() => this.androidFullScreen.showSystemUI());

     // style statusbar and hide splash
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.statusBar.styleDefault();
         this.splashScreen.hide();
     });
   }
   ...
   ```

Comment: Works like a charm +1

Comment: But I needed to change de package version to: `npm install --save @ionic-native/android-full-screen@4`

Answer (score 0):

For Android, If you have a splash with single colored background change status bar to same color.

Add following in `styles.xml` (I'm showing status bar with white background)

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```