# edit-config for ios usage descriptions: doc.find is not a function

Tags: ios, cordova

When using the `edit-config` tag in `config.xml`, I get this error on build:

```
Error: doc.find is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13564 ??

Comment: Most likely! Thanks

Comment: An alternative to add those usage descriptions is: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

Comment: Thanks, the expert replied ;)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

I think that the error has thrown when the `platforms/ios/ios.json` file is conflicting to the `config.xml`.

To resolve this issue, remove `*-Info.plist` key and its value in `platforms/ios/ios.json` and do `cordova prepare ios` again.

--- adding 17/May/2020 ---

If some plugins has `config-file` tag for `*-Info.plist` and config.xml has `edit-config` tag for `*-Info.plist`, this error may happen.
In this case, remove `platforms/*` and `plugins/*`, and then
`cordova platform add ios` and `cordova prepare` again.
(If you do `cordova prepare` without `cordova platform add ios`, this error may happen)

Comment: Nice solution considering how uninformative this crap error is!

Comment: If this solution does not work for you, go to your platforms > ios > ios.json file and within the *-Info.plist parent key, add the new value that was added to the config.xml file. For example, if you add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription edit-config tag, add:
`"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": [
            {
              "xml": "<string>Need photo library access to get pictures from there.</string>",
              "count": 1,
              "mode": "merge",
              "id": "config.xml"
            }
          ],`

Comment: This helped but have a read on this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558496/1176567). If you just remove cordova ios platform and add it again, it would work. This problem occurs when ios platform is already added and then we update the config.xml with <edit-config>.

Comment: Just fixed the issue by using <config-file> instead (other answer)

Answer (score 67):

There is an existing issue with `<edit-config>` conflicting with `platforms/ios/ios.json` when `*-Info.plist` is already populated in the `json` file as of Cordova 7.1.0

I have fixed the issue by using `<config-file>` instead.

**Solution:**

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Apple is now requesting `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, this solves my issue, thx a lot!

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Comment: This does nothing differently.

Comment: Work on my side, thanks

Comment: This is the better answer as the accepted one asks you to run `cordova platform add ios` whenever you want to run your project after a clean install. Which is not acceptable. Especially in CI environments.

Answer (score 39):

I have done this with `Ionic 3`. Working fine now :)

***Solution:***

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Re-adding the iOS platform will freshly create the `ios.json` file.

Comment: Amazing! Couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: This is kind of a nuclear option... don't try it first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, brute force on this case works just fine

```
cordova platform rm ios && cordova platform add ios
```

You shouldn't care what's inside `platform/ios` because the directory `platforms` is volatile in cordova, nor should be tracked on git projects.