# Cordova iOS build fails with 'edit-config' tag

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic 3 app (**Ionic CLI 3.19.0, Cordova CLI 8.0.0, android platform 7.0.0,
ios platform 4.5.4**) that includes the native 'Geolocation' plugin.  Since iOS 10+ requires the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` property in the App-Info.plist file, the plugin's documentation ([Geolocation iOS Quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks)) says to include the following in the config.xml:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
   <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```

So I added that verbatim as the first entry within `<platform name="ios">...</platform>` tag of my config.xml.

During the cordova iOS stage of the build, it fails with the following obscure errors:

> (node:60604)UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: doc.find is not a function
>
> (node:60604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I found that removing and then adding the iOS platform resolves the issue.  However, this breaks some of the plugins used as they require the platform to be installed first.  Thus, I have to reinstall those plugins.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comment above, the steps needed are:

- Remove platforms ios: **cordova platform remove ios**
- Add the **edit-config** into **platform name="ios"** tag

  `<platform name="ios"> Add me here </platform>`
- Run prepare ios: **ionic cordova prepare ios**

Comment: Along with this answer, this other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48182065/763010) helped me identify any existing `NS*` strings within the `ios.json` file, which I was then able to migrate to the `config.xml` file as new entries within the `<platform name="ios">` tag, thus retaining all existing values.

Answer (score 1):

and set it in the right format

```
<edit-config parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>need location access to to order a driver to the current location</string>
</edit-config>
```